# Insert entity with one related entity which existed in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am stuck at the operation when using Entity Framework Core 2 to perform an insert of a new entity with one related entity which already existed in the database. For example, I have two objects with **one to many** relationship:

```
public Class OrderDetail
{
   public int ParentID {get;set;}
   public string OrderDetailName {get;set;}
   public int ProductID {get;set;}
   public virtual Product ProductFK {get;set;}
}

public Class Product
{
   public int ProductID {get;set;}
   public string ProductName {get;set;}
   public virtual Collection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails {get;set;} = new Collection<OrderDetail>();
}
```

I would like to add a new `OrderDetail` with an existing `Product` (with `productID = 3`) into the database, so I perform like:

```
private void AddOrderDetail(int productID)
{
    OrderDetail newOrderDetail = new OrderDetail();
    newOrderDetail.Name = "New OrderDetail";

    // Here I have no clue what would be the correct way...Should I do 
    // Approach A(pick related entity from database then assign as related entity to base entity):
    var ProductFromDB = DbContext.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ProductID == productID);
    newOrderDetail.ProductFK = ProductFromDB;

    // Approach B(directly assign the foreign key value to base entity)
    newOrderDetail.ProductID = productID

    DbContext.SaveChange();
}
```

By using approach **(A)**, my `newOrderDetail` failed to save and I looked into SQL resource, looks like it considered the one that I retrieved from the database (`ProductFromDB`) as a new object and was trying to insert it again. I feel it's redundant job for picking `ProductFromDB` first then assign to the inserted entity...

By using approach **(B)**, my `newOrderDetail` still failed to save, and I am getting an exception like "insert A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.", however, this exception does not happen constantly. I looked into the SQL and found the SQL Script, by running it individually in SQL Server it worked, however when running an application side, it's not working...

So what would be the correct way to deal with above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need access to the complete `Product` object right away, you could try to set just the foreign key column value of your `newOrderDetail`. Also, you need to **ADD** your newly created `OrderDetail` object to the `DbContext` before saving - something like this:

```
private void AddOrderDetail(int productID)
{
    OrderDetail newOrderDetail = new OrderDetail();
    newOrderDetail.Name = "New OrderDetail";
    newOrderDetail.ProductID = productID

    // OF COURSE, you need to ADD the newly created object to the context!
    DbContext.OrderDetails.Add(newOrderDetail);

    DbContext.SaveChange();
}
```

Next time around, when you actually fetch the `OrderDetail`, it will resolve the linked product and you should be fine.:

```
using (var DbContext = new YourDbContext())
{
    OrderDetail od = DbContext.OrderDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name = "New OrderDetail");
    ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: So what if I want to save a new Product with a collection of existed OrderDetails, from API I can get a list of OrderDetailID in an array, should I need to fetch each OrderDetail from database (by OrderDetailID) then add to the Product's OrderDetails Collection? I am not sure that's the correct way but seems like it drops a lot of performance...

Comment: @KevinDing: seems like a highly unlikely business scenario - adding a new product to a list of existing orders...... is this just for the sake of discussion, or do you **actually** have such a business case?? But yes - if you ever need to grab a whole collection to store - of course that will be slower than storing just a single object - no doubt about it.

Comment: thank you so much! Sorry If I did not describe correctly, this time I was trying to save a single object but it has a collection of its related entities which are already existed in the database, I have opened a new ticket on that [Entity Framework Core - insert entity with multiple related entities which existed in the database][1] [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51120596/entity-framework-core-insert-entity-with-a-collection-of-related-entities-whic

Comment: i tried doing this and found that there in total two db calls one for fetching product and other for inserting the new record. any way to avoid this?