# Insert entity with a collection of related entities which already exist in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two objects with a many-to-one relationship:

```
public class Product
{
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public virtual Collection<ProductInventory> ProductInventorys { get; set; } = new Collection<ProductInventory>();
}

public class ProductInventory
{
   public int ProductInventoryID { get; set; }
   public string ProductInventoryName { get; set; }
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   public virtual Product ProductFK { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add a new `Product` with a collection of existing `ProductInventory` (my API would have an input of `ProductInventoryID` array) into the database, so I perform like:

```
private void AddProduct(int[] productInventoryIDs)
{
    Product newProduct = new Product();
    newProduct.Name = "New Product";

    // Here I have no clue which would be the correct way...should I use 

    // Approach A - fetch each related "ProductInventory" entity from database,
    // then add them into the collection of my new base entity - Product)
    productInventoryIDs.ToList().Foreach(p => 
        {
            newProduct.ProductInventorys.Add(_dbContext.ProductInventory.FindById(p))
        }
    );

    _dbContext.Products.Add(newProduct);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // Approach B: Save base "Product" entity first, then grab the new ProductID, 
    // then fetch each "ProductInventory" from database and assign the foreign key with the new "ProductID" value, and then save each
    _dbContext.Products.Add(newProduct);
    var newProductID = _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    productInventoryIDs.ToList().Foreach(pi => 
        {
            var existedProductInventoryFromDb = _dbContext.ProductInventory.FindById(pi)；
            existedProductInventoryFromDb.ProductID = newProductID；
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    );
}
```

- By using approach **(A)**, my `newProduct` failed to save and I looked into SQL resource, looks like it is trying to insert `ProductInventory` as well, although these `ProductInventory` already exist in the database. I guess that's because I add them into my base entity's collection?
- By using approach **(B)**, I am feeling a little awkward for doing that as it's like fetching and saving multiple times for just one object, I doubt if I am doing the correct way...

Maybe I am wrong at both approaches, so what would be the correct way to deal with above scenario?

Comment: One obvious improvement for approach (B) would be to call the `.SaveChanges()` only **once**, after the `.Foreach()` loop ..... or you could encapsulate this whole functionality into a stored procedure in the database and just make that one stored procedure call to update all relevant products - in one database call, instead of loading all n products just to set a single value on them ....

Comment: It's unclear to me what are you trying to achieve. With the sample model, the result would be disassociating existing products from their existing orders and associating them with a new order, which doesn't sound logical to me (needs confirmation if that's the desired behavior). It would make more sense if the product is separate entity not owned by order, but having many-to-many relationship with it, e.g. Order 1 <-> 0..N OrderProduct 0..N <-> 1 Product.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, I got what you're confusing, so I opened a new ticket at [insert entity with many to many related entities which existed in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127858/entity-framework-core-insert-entity-with-many-to-many-related-entities-which-e), maybe this is not a good business scenario, but if just for the sake of discussion , what would be the right way of doing that?

Comment: @Ivan Stoev, I have changed the object relationship from Object - Product to Product to Product Inventory, which might be a better business scenario of many to one relationship...

Comment: @marc_s, thank you for the advice! I know I could use store procedure but just tried to avoid using it here. In approach B, the first .SaveChange() is used to get the new Saved Product ID, which I think it's mandatory. But yes, I got what you're suggesting, so instead of calling multiple .SaveChange() within the for loop, you're suggesting call only once after the loop, correct? However, why the Approach A failed here...does it mean Entity Framework only works with Foreign Key value assignment but not with related entity objects assignment?