# Insert entity with many to many related entities which exist in the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have two objects with **many to many** relationship:

```
public class Order
{
   public int OrderID { get; set; }
   public string OrderName { get; set; }
   public virtual Collection<Product> Products { get; set; } = new Collection<Product>();
}

public class Product
{
   public int ProductID { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public int OrderID { get; set; }
   public virtual Collection<Order> Orders { get; set; } = new Collection<Order>();
}

// Mapping table
public class OrderProduct
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public Order Order { get; set; }
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
   public Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to add a new Order with a collection of existing Products (my API would have an input of ProductID array) into the database, so I perform like:

```
private void AddOrder(int[] productIDs)
{
    Order newOrder = new Order();
    newOrder.Name = "New Order";

    // Here I have no clue which would be the correct way...Should I do 
    // Approach A(fetch each related entity - Product from database then add them into the collection of my new base entity - Order):
    productIDs.ToList().Foreach(p => 
        {
            newOrder.Products.Add(_dbContext.Product.FindById(p))
        }
    );

    _dbContext.Orders.Add(newOrder);
    var newOrderID = _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    // then fetch each product from database and add my new Order to its collection and save
    productIDs.ToList().Foreach(p => 
        {
            var existedProductFromDb = _dbContext.Product.FindById(p)；
            existedProductFromDb.Orders.Add(newOrder);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    );
}
```

Do I really need the Mapping table between Order and Product in Entity Framework Core? Otherwise, what would be the correct way to deal with above scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entities do not represent a many-to-many relationship using a joined table. In fact, you don't use the joining table at all.

So, start by fixing your entities:

```
public class Order
{
   public int OrderID {get;set;}
   public string OrderName {get;set;}

   public ICollection<OrderProduct> Products { get; set; } = new HashSet<OrderProduct>();
}

public class Product
{
   public int ProductID {get;set;}
   public string ProductName {get;set;}

   public ICollection<OrderProduct> Orders { get; set; } = new HashSet<OrderProduct>();
}
```

A new `Order` which contains many `Product`s is as simple as a collection of new `OrderProduct`s:

```
private void AddOrder(int[] productIDs)
{
    Order newOrder = new Order();
    newOrder.Name = "New Order";

    foreach (int productId in productIDs)
    {
        newOrder.Products.Add(new OrderProduct { ProductId = productId });
    }

    _dbContext.Orders.Add(newOrder);
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Also, do notice that `SaveChanges` returns the number of affected rows in the database, not the Id of an inserted item.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I know where I make mistakes now! However, I have that mapping table in database, by using your way, do I still need to define the OrderProduct class in C#? In addition, there is a 'Order ID' in Product class, I guess that should also be removed, right?

Comment: @KevinDing Yes, my bad, I should have deleted that `OrderId` property. And yes, you need to define `OrderProduct` since a many-to-many relationship is not actually logical and can only be modeled as two one-to-many relationships.